# What will be the pdf when Chi-square distribtion function is multiplying by variance

Tags: statistics

What will be the pdf of given function in which $\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}(x^2[n]/\sigma^2)$ is Chi-square distribtion function  multiplying by variance $\sigma^2$ :

$\sigma^2\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}(x^2[n]/\sigma^2)$

Comment: "pdf of given function in which.." What exactly do you mean? Usually we speak of the pdf a random variable or of a distribution.

Comment: given function meams:$\sigma^2\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}(x^2[n]/\sigma^2)$

Comment: Do you know the PDF of $\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}(x^2[n]/\sigma^2)$? If so then you can just apply my hint with $c=\sigma^2$

Comment: yes I know its pdf.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If rv $X$ has PDF: $$f(x)$$ and $c>0$ then $cX$ has PDF: $$\frac{1}{c}f(\frac{x}{c})$$

Comment: that was that I want to know, thanks